# Swift - Store Text in Audio File (e.g. MP3)

Tags: swift, cocoa, audio, mp3, storing-data

I would like to know a way to store text inside audio file (using Objective-C or Swift). The audio file is still playable, however. I had tried to ask google but I couldn't find anything. Thank you!

This is the sample file. If you use Hex editor, you can see there is text added on the top of the MP3 file. Still, it's playable.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_WKeofBcSEHS3BoQ05weHVaMG8

Comment: Do you mean like ID3 tags?

Comment: Does ID3 tags have custom tag to append the information which is not related to the MP3 itself?

Comment: I guess you could _technically_ put any information you want in an ID3 tag but it was created to hold information about the audio file. However, if you are trying to hide the text, the ID3 tag is very readable and not hidden by any means.

Comment: I actually ran across an app that add text to mp3 file. I can see the text inside the file, but I cannot see that text inside any ID3 tags from ID3 tag editor. Thus, I assume the text was kept in a custom or private tag? which is not able to edit directly from tag editor. I tried to look through the metadata with code but no luck. :(

Comment: ```
`import AVFoundation`
`var asset = AVAsset(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("audio", ofType: "mp3")!))`
`for metadata in asset.metadata {`
`  print(metadata.key)`
`  print(metadata.value)`  
`  // "PRIV" private frame`
`}`

What is the PRIV frame about?

Comment: You can use [extended attribute](http://nshipster.com/extended-file-attributes/) but (a) it only works on Mac OS X, and (b) not all disk formats support it. If you copy the MP3 from HFS to a USB formatted at FAT32, you lose those attributes